# Expose a function from a functional component - React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a functional component `Form`. I need to expose a function `validate` from it.

Validate will typically use state variables inside the form.

Now, I'm unable to think of a way to expose it such that whichever component uses `form`, it can simply validate form like below

```
 const { validateForm } = Form;
 const isFormValid = validateForm();
```

Provided my Form look like below

```
const Form = () => {
    const isError = () => {}
    const isEmpty = () => {}
    const validate = () => {
        return isError() || isEmpty();
    }
}
```

**Is there a way to do it via hooks? I cannot just get my head around at this moment.**

P.S - I completely understand it breaks the philosophy of declarative and is an imperative way but there are use cases where this is required. Esp. when people expose it via libraries. Ant design does that too - https://ant.design/components/form/

So I am completely fine with it.

Comment: Yes there is an imperative way; not a declarative one. writing a codesandbox demo

Comment: @MohamedELAYADI please do. You can hint me too. Maybe it is just not striking me.

Comment: AH sorry just saw you comment, the hint is to use the `useImperativeHandle` hook

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can do it combining `useRef` and `useImperativeHandle` by doing the following:

- Your `Form` must be forwarding ref using `React.forwardRef`.

`const MyForm = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {`

- Declare the form validation inside the form component by using the `useImperativeHandle` hook this way:

```
  React.useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    validate: () => {
      alert("now, the form is validating");
    }
  }));
```

- In the form's parent, create a ref and pass it to your form `<MyForm ref={formRef} />`

Then in your event just use `formRef.current.validate();`

Please find a demo in [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-dream-o10vh)

Comment: I updated the demo to expect a return value from the validation rather than displaying the alert from the form

Comment: Ah! How nice. I was testing that only:)

Comment: Hello. this is a breaking change for my component. For example, I will no longer be able to do `<Form.Item>` as `Item` was attached to Form object which is now wrapped with forwardRef function. What do you suggest here?

Comment: The forward ref only forwards the ref from the parent and make it accessible from the cild. it should not impact your logic. If you could please submit a codesandbox illustrating your issue si we can help